# Facebook Login Handler doesn't get fired in Flex4 Facebook API

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, apache-flex, flex4

I have literally spent HOURS trying to solve this mystery... but simply can't seem to get hold of it.
I am using the same code lines (literally!) as the example [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/flex_fbgraph_pt3.html) (official adobe tutorial)  and I get different result.

```
protected function login():void
{
    Facebook.login(loginHandler,{perms:"user_birthday,read_stream,publish_stream"});
}

protected function loginHandler(success:Object,fail:Object):void
{
    trace ("login handler called");
    if(success){    
        currentState="state_home"; 
        Facebook.api("/me",getMeHandler);
        //userImg.source=Facebook.getImageUrl(success.uid,"small");
        Facebook.api("/me/statuses",getStatusHandler);
    } 
}
```

Everything works fine, i.e. everything till it is time to fire the loggedin event. I get asked to log in and all permissions are asked correctly. After I log myself in to facebook, the loggedin event doesn't fire. Is there any way of solving this problem??

And I am really desparate... :(

Comment: other than just using another browser, did you ever figure out what was causing this? I tried using firefox 4 and safari, it's letting me log in just like you, but it's not triggering the loginHandler Function for some reason.

Comment: I am not sure anymore, its been some time since I have worked on it (exams you know:( ) but I think it had something to do with parameter "Allow Script Access" in embedding javascript, plus try your web application in another computer, sometimes a browser behaves differently due to some old crappy plugin you installed! maybe it is going to work just fine everywhere else!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried debugging the JavaScript of the containing HTML page? I've found that the JavaScript can encounter errors in the communication back to your Flash movie, and it fails silently in the background.

Open the debugger and have a look for any errors - sometimes its down to conflicting embed object Ids in the HTML that throws it.

Comment: thanks for the answer... But i found out it works fine in Explorer, Safari and Chrome, but it doesn't work in Opera, where I was incidentally testing my app :)